# pyspark is not recognizing table from outside sql subquery

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have registered two tables as temp views

```
ldf.createOrReplaceTempView("loan")
mdf.createOrReplaceTempView("mkt")
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM loan join (select * from mkt where loan.id >= mkt.id) as m on loan.qtr = m.qtr limit 1")
df.show()
```

However when I run this command pyspark fails to recognize the loan view inside the subquery. The error makes it seem like it can only see tables/views that are inside the subquery. It's not even looking in the loan view.

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'loan.id' given input columns: [mkt.id, mkt.lo, mkt.qtr]
```

Comment: `(select * from mkt where loan.id >= mkt.id)` - this derived table does not contain a column named load_id.  It looks to me like you should be able to just join to mkt on load_id = mkt.id and loan.qtr = mkt.qtr, instead of using the derived table

Comment: The column name is not load_id. It's id, and it is present in the loan view. I just don't understand why spark isn't even looking in the loan view in this subquery.

Comment: Because the loan view is not in scope for your derived table. You are over-complicating this. `from loan join mkt on load_id >= mkt_id and loan.qtr = m.qtr`

Comment: Yeah, this is just a test query. I have much more complicated logic which will require the correlated subquery. I just want to understand why this view is apparently not in scope. In standard sql this works fine. I don't know why pyspark sql can't do this

Comment: You don't have a correlated subquery, you have a derived table.  Very different things.

Answer (score 0):

The current query is the following,

```
SELECT * 
FROM loan 
JOIN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM mkt 
    WHERE loan.id >= mkt.id
) AS m 
    ON loan.qtr = m.qtr limit 1
```

The nested select statement that defines `m` does not know what `loan` is or what `loan.id` is. Therefore it's unable to make the comparison between `loan.id` and `mkt.id`.

I tested this current query format using both MySQL and PrestoSQL and both returned "Column cannot be resolved" error messages. These error messages align with the Spark SQL error message you received.

Instead you can compare columns from `loan` and `mkt` after joining the datasets together.

```
SELECT * 
FROM loan 
JOIN mkt ON loan.qtr = mkt.qtr 
WHERE loan.id >= mkt.id 
LIMIT 1
```

Run via Spark SQL it looks like,

`df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM loan JOIN mkt ON loan.qtr = mkt.qtr WHERE loan.id >= mkt.id LIMIT 1")`